# Алфавитный алгоритм

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Требуется из цифры 1 получить *A*, из 2 получить *B*, из 3 получить *C* и тд до Z. Как это сделать?

Comment: `(char)('A' + x - 1)`

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Ну, э, а почему не ответ? Ну да, простой ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(char)('A' + x - 1)
```

Спасибо *@АндрейNOP* за ответ.